# for loop in Dust templates

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I am using NodeJS/Express3 and dusts-linkedin and would like to do the equivalent of:

```
for(var i = locals.first;i < (locals.first + locals.pages); $i++) {
    <div>i</div>
}
```

I assume I need to create a helper function but am unclear on how to do so

Comment: Can you give a little more clarity on what the `locals` object is supposed to look like?

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out - will post my answer

Answer (score 5):

Ok. In my case I was trying to create a pager but I'm going to simplify the answer a bit so that one can get the general idea. There may be a cleaner way to do this.

My helper will be called 'pager'. I have some express variables in locals that I will want to pass. These are locals.start and locals.end - each is a number representing my pager start and end. I will also pass a url to use for the pager.

In my template I call the helper along with all the parameters I may need:

```
{@pager start="{locals.start}" end="{locals.end}" url="/articles?page=%page%"/}
```

Then in my app.'s I will add this helper. I need to make sure my dust module is present:

```
cons = require('consolidate'),
dust = require('dustjs-linkedin'),
```

Then create the helper:

```
dust.helpers['pager'] = function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {

  //tapping these to get the actual value (since we passed vsaraibles) and casting as a number with '+'
  first = +dust.helpers.tap(params.first, chunk, context);
  last = +dust.helpers.tap(params.last, chunk, context);

  //this one is all ready since we just passed a string
  url = params.url;

  //build our html - do whatever you need here - this is an example
  var html = '<ul>';
  for(var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    //I used a replace and placeholder - prob other methods you can use
    html += '<li><a href="' + url.replace('%page%', i) + '">' + i '</a></li>';
  }
  html += '</ul>';

  //write this back to the template
  chunk.write(html);

  //return it
  return chunk;
};
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, funny I was actually also trying to build pagination too, this is way better than doing a simple loop